# Can't convert string to float. Its showing error "could not convert string to float: 'None'"

Tags: django, django-views

Im working a Django project that gets my deivce location and shows the nearest places. Ive manage to pass the cordinates to the views module but I cant change from "str" to "float". It shows the error "could not convert string to float: 'None'".

This is my code

Template (index.html)

```
<h1> Pharmacy Finder </h1>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<p id="demo"></p> 

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML =position.coords.latitude + 
  "," + position.coords.longitude;



  var lat = x;
  
  $.ajax({
    url:'',
    type: 'get',
    data: {location: $(lat).text()}

  });

}
```

View (views.py)

```
from contextlib import nullcontext
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


\#finder imports
import time
import googlemaps
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
import numpy as np
import re

\#Google Maps API Key
API_KEY = 'AIzaSyAffT1NSiYnE4n_4v8No2GCYUqKp-XLtcc'
map_client = googlemaps.Client(API_KEY)

Rlatitude = 0
Rlongitude = 0

def index(request):
    global Rlatitude
    global Rlongitude

    text = request.GET.get('location')
    a = str(text)
    cordinates = re.split('\,',a)
    
    
    for ls in range(len(cordinates)):
        if ls ==0:
            Rlatitude = cordinates[ls]
        elif ls>0:
            Rlongitude = cordinates[ls]
    
    
    #the error is here:
    
    print(type(Rlatitude))
    print(Rlatitude)
    
    if Rlatitude != 0:
        print(Rlatitude)
        a  = float(Rlatitude)
    
    
    #Please ignore these lines of codes
    my_dict = {'insert_me':'hi'}
    return render(request,'finder/index.html',context=my_dict)
```

I tried converting to float using "float(value)"

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the data that you're getting from the request is not good. You're not getting a number but you're getting a `None` so that's where you have to look.

I would start by adding a `print("GET Request : ", request.GET)` at the top of your view to see what type of data you're receiving.

---

If i had to guess i'd say that the error is here:

```
var lat = x;
```

try replacing it with this:

```
var lat = x.textContent;
```

P.S. It's always better to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if you have the option because `innerHTML` is more exposed to javascript injection attacks.

Comment: Hi there, firstly thank you helping me with this. Ive made the changes as said. Im getting "GET Request :  <QueryDict: {}>"